# Running powershell scripts on remote machine

Tags: powershell

I am trying to execute a powershell script on a remote computer. The script opens a notepad application, creates a file and saves it. I run the script with below command in source machine:

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "na18actxdc" -ScriptBlock {D:\NMAutomation\trial_2.ps1}

The command runs for a long time on source machine and breaks. But the text file is not created.  Could anyone help here please ?

However the same script when executed from the remote machine, executes faster and the text file gets saved. I have tried the same concept with autoit scripts and psexec options. None of them works.

Code on remote machine:

```
Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\AutoItX\AutoItX.psd1"
Invoke-AU3Run -Program notepad.exe
$windowtitle ="Untitled - Notepad"
Wait-AU3WinActive($windowtitle)
$windowhandle = Get-AU3WinHandle -Title $windowtitle
Show-AU3WinActivate -WinHandle $windowhandle 
Send-AU3Key("I'm in notepad"); 
$windowhandle = Get-AU3WinHandle($windowtitle);
$controlHandle = Get-AU3ControlHandle -WinHandle $windowhandle -Control  "Edit1"
Send-AU3ControlKey -ControlHandle $controlHandle -Key "{ENTER}simulate key strokes - line 1" -WinHandle $windowhandle
Close-AU3Win($windowtitle)
$windowtitlesaveas = "Save As"
$windowhandlesaveas = Get-AU3WinHandle ($windowtitlesaveas)
$controlHandlesaveas = Get-AU3ControlHandle -WinHandle $windowhandlesaveas -Control "Edit1"
$windowhandlesaveas -NewText "sample"
$controlHandlesaveas -Key "sample"
Invoke-AU3ControlClick -Title "Notepad" -Control "Button1" -NumClicks 1 
Wait-AU3WinActive("Save As")
Set-AU3ControlText -Title "Save As" -Control "Edit1" -NewText "sample" 
Send-AU3ControlKey -Title "Save As" -Control "Button1" -Key "{ENTER}"
```

Comment: Can you try this please: `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName na18actxdc` and then 
`D:\NMAutomation\trial_2.ps1`. I have a feeling that Autoit cmdlets that are meant for an interactive window will fail to work in a commandline session.

Comment: Did anything happen with this?

Comment: Are you trying to have the script interact with application windows remotely?

Answer (score 1):

From [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote?view=powershell-6):

> HOW TO RUN A SCRIPT ON REMOTE COMPUTERS
>
> To run a local script on remote computers, use the FilePath parameter of Invoke-Command.
>
> For example, the following command runs the Sample.ps1 script on the S1 and S2 computers:
>
> PowerShell
>
> Invoke-Command -ComputerName S1, S2 -FilePath C:\Test\Sample.ps1
>
> The results of the script are returned to the local computer. You do not need to copy any files.

Change

```
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName "na18actxdc" -ScriptBlock {D:\NMAutomation\trial_2.ps1}
```

to

```
   Invoke-Command -ComputerName "na18actxdc" -FilePath D:\NMAutomation\trial_2.ps1
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes I have tried but not getting the desired output

Comment: Define this a bit more, or you leave us to guess.

Comment: @Neeraja, as asked as comment in your question: `Where is the script situated on your machine or on the remote one?`

Comment: For Scriptblock attribute I placed the script on remote machine; For Filepath attribute I placed it in the source machine

Answer (score 1):

I think what is happening here is that by running this: `Invoke-Command -ComputerName "na18actxdc" -ScriptBlock {D:\NMAutomation\trial_2.ps1}` the ps1 does not get executed but simply opened in a notepad process.

I believe what you have to do is to try and tell it to run it in powershell.

`Invoke-Command -ComputerName "na18actxdc" -ScriptBlock {PowerShell.exe -File D:\NMAutomation\trial_2.ps1}`

Comment: I have tried using powershell.exe but the script runs for more than 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

To verify that what you are trying to do is even possible with powershell remoting, you should verify that it can run in a live PSSession.

That can be done like this:

```
PS C:\Users\XXX> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName "na18actxdc"
[na18actxdc]: PS C:\Users\XXX\Documents> D:\NMAutomation\trial_2.ps1
```

If script runs successfully, then I don't see why Invoke-Command shouldn't work. 
If you still experience problems, try writing out some debug messages.